# Pandas: Get duplicated indexes

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

Given a dataframe, I want to get the duplicated indexes, which do not have duplicate values in the columns, and see which values are different.

Specifically, I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmimze2g4lt4ud3/alt_exon_repeatmasker_intersect.bed
alt_exon_repeatmasker = pd.read_table('alt_exon_repeatmasker_intersect.bed', header=None, index_col=3)

In [74]: alt_exon_repeatmasker.index.is_unique
Out[74]: False
```

And some of the indexes have duplicate values in the 9th column (the type of DNA repetitive element in this location), and I want to know what are the different types of repetitive elements for individual locations (each index = a genome location).

I'm guessing this will require some kind of `groupby` and hopefully some `groupby` ninja can help me out.

To simplify even further, if we only have the index and the repeat type,

```
genome_location1    MIR3
genome_location1    AluJb
genome_location2    Tigger1
genome_location3    AT_rich
```

So the output I'd like to see all duplicate indexes and their repeat types, as such:

```
genome_location1    MIR3
genome_location1    AluJb
```

EDIT: added toy example

Comment: Hi, usually it's good practice to simplify question as much as possible and create toy example with input and desired output. Such a questions are answered much faster and will be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['type']
```

We added `filter` method for this kind of operation. You can also use masking and transform for equivalent results, but this is faster, and a little more readable too.

**Important:**

The `filter` method was introduced in version 0.12, but it failed to work on DataFrames/Series with nonunique indexes. The issue -- and a related issue with `transform` on Series -- was fixed for version 0.13, which should be released any day now.

Clearly, nonunique indexes are the heart of this question, so I should point out that this approach will not help until you have pandas 0.13. In the meantime, the `transform` workaround is the way to go. Be ware that if you try that on a *Series* with a nonunique index, it too will fail.

There is no good reason why `filter` and `transform` should not be applied to nonunique indexes; it was just poorly implemented at first.

Comment: this one is not working for me, I've tried even `df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: True)`, receiving `Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`.

Comment: Good catch! This particular use encounters a bug that was fixed for v0.13, which obviously many users do not have. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still on 0.12 and will stick to it until v0.13 is fully released because I'm sharing a codebase and `virtualenv` messes everything up for me. I'll switch to this once we upgrade! Thanks! I've been using `pandas` for a year but I'm still wrapping my mind around `groupby`s

Comment: When looking at efficiency, I doubt this is faster than `df.set_index('type').index.duplicates` - since it has to iterate through every single group in order to perform, instead of looking at it "from outside the groups".

Comment: I didn't know about `index.duplicates`. Add it as an answer; that's definitely better.

Answer (score 89):

Also useful and very succinct:

`df[df.index.duplicated()]`

Note that this only returns one of the duplicated rows, so to see all the duplicated rows you'll want this:

`df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: There is a great example in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html)

Comment: **Example Usage**: 1. `idx = pd.Index(['lama', 'cow', 'lama', 'beetle', 'lama'])` 2. `idx.duplicated()`
3. `array([False, False,  True, False,  True])`

Answer (score 22):

Even faster and better:

```
df.index.get_duplicates()
```

Comment: good answer but it comes with future warning for pandas 0.23.4 
`'get_duplicates' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. You can use idx[idx.duplicated()].unique() instead`

Answer (score 9):

As of 9/21/18 Pandas indicates `FutureWarning: 'get_duplicates' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release`, instead suggesting the following:

```
df.index[df.index.duplicated()].unique()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> df[df.groupby(level=0).transform(len)['type'] > 1]
                   type
genome_location1   MIR3
genome_location1  AluJb
```

Comment: or, very similarly, with ``filter`` like so: ``df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['type']``. Will be faster than transforming and masking.

Comment: @DanAllan great, may be you add another answer and OP'll accept it?

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer since it's guaranteed to work with the current release of `pandas`.

Comment: I think that's the right choice. Useful conversation, all around.

Answer (score 2):

More succinctly:

```
df[df.groupby(level=0).type.count() > 1]
```

FYI a multi-index:

```
df[df.groupby(level=[0,1]).type.count() > 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

This gives you index values along with a preview of duplicated rows

```
def dup_rows_index(df):
  dup = df[df.duplicated()]
  print('Duplicated index loc:',dup[dup == True ].index.tolist())
  return dup
```