# Pandas : change the index of the duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have 2 DataFrames : `df0` and `df1` and `df1.shape[0] > df1.shape[0]`.

`df0` and `df1` have the exact same columns.
Most of the rows of `df0` are in `df1`.

The indices of `df0` and `df1` are

```
df0.index = range(df0.shape[0])
df1.index = range(df1.shape[0])
```

I then created `dft`

```
dft = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=0, sort=False)
```

and removed duplicated rows with

```
dft.drop_duplicates(subset='this_col_is_not_index', keep='first', inplace=True)
```

I have some duplicates on the index of `dft`. For example :

```
dft.loc[3].shape
```

returns

```
(2, 38)
```

My aim is to change the index of the second row returned to have a unique index `3`.
This second row should be indexed `dft.index.sort_values()[-1]+1`.

I would like to apply this operation on all duplicates.

References :

[Python Pandas: Get index of rows which column matches certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800169/python-pandas-get-index-of-rows-which-column-matches-certain-value)

[Pandas: Get duplicated indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199129/pandas-get-duplicated-indexes)

[Redefining the Index in a Pandas DataFrame object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457584/redefining-the-index-in-a-pandas-dataframe-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) for avoid duplicated index values:

```
dft = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=0, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reset_index(drop = True)

```
dft.reset_index(drop=True)
```